# iOS7 Constraint crashes without any usefull details

Tags: ios, swift, ios7, autolayout

List item

I have one view in which elements are created by code and constraints for autoLayout are being set;

All elements are being attached to either the view above and below or to the superview's top or bottom.

so I Iterate over all the views, in general it's only one or two of them.

```
or obj:AnyObject in container.subviews {
            if let v = obj as? UIView {
                constraints.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: v, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Left, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: container, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Left, multiplier: 1, constant: 16))
                constraints.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: v, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Right, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: container, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Right, multiplier: 1, constant: -16))
//                constraints.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: v, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 30))
                constraints.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: v, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.GreaterThanOrEqual, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 20))
            }
        }
```

This code works on iOS7 because of the commented line, however I actually need the height constraint so I can see the views, (they are FormTextFields).

All works fine in iOS8 Of course the first 2 constraints used to be Leading and Trailing I believe those crashed on iOS 7 aswell.

Anyone have any ideas what could cause the problems?

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using, and do you remember the version of Xcode that originally created the Storyboard?  I had a problem last summer where my Storyboard was crashing, but when I re-created it with the latest version of Xcode, everything worked fine.

Comment: I would print out the existing constraints to see what is there before you append to see if there is anything that could clash. e.g. constraints created by the system. You should also probably have `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` set to NO for all the container views.

Comment: I made it in 6.3 and still am in 6.3 :(.

@RoryMcKinnel, Yes I do set this option. fyi it works just perfectly on iOS8. I'll have to look into It deeper I guess.

Comment: @MathijsSegers Something else you could try is to not directly adjust the constraints array using `append`. Instead use the method `addConstraint`. It could be that these methods do more than just add the constraint to the array. Especially in iOS7. The method would be the more correct way to add constraints I think as well.

Comment: oh, the constraints array is just an array of constraints which are added later using addConstraints on the superview

Comment: @MathijsSegers Ah, ok. Mistook it for being the constraints property of the view. I guess you need to dump the existing constraints to see what is going on. Odd though as constraints usually get broken and reported on the console rather than causing a crash. Is there no console output or stack trace when it crashes?

Comment: nope there isn't. I actually fiddled around with the code, and put some constraints in a different order, and everything is working fine now... Sometimes I really don' t know what i'm doing in iOS and I don't like this!